# Can't retrieve spotify api token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, spotify

I am using the react-spotify-login package and when trying to authorize the application I can't retrieve the access token. My routing works and sending the request works. I just can't retrieve the token. I've just started learning react so I'm hoping it isn't something I'm easily overlooking.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SpotifyLogin from 'react-spotify-login';
import { clientId, redirectUri } from '../../Settings';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';




export class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        const onSuccess = ({ response }) => {
            //const { access_token: token } = response;
            console.log("[onSuccess]" + response);
            return <Redirect to='/home' />
        };

        const onFailure = response => console.error("[onFailure]" + response);

        return (
            <div>
                <SpotifyLogin
                    clientId={clientId}
                    redirectUri={redirectUri}
                    onSuccess={onSuccess}
                    onFailure={onFailure}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: what do you mean, "I just can't retrieve the token"?

Comment: What does the `response` look like? What does it print to the console?

Comment: I receive the error "Error: 'access_token' not found" in the response and what I mean by "I can't just receive the token" is that the application seems to be routing properly to the Login component and making the request but I receive the error stated previously instead of the token

Comment: Update: When trying to run same code in the App.js file the OnSuccess function gets called but response is undefined.

Comment: I don't know the specific library, but from the code it looks like onSuccess is expecting parameters which you're not passing. would need something like `onSuccess={() => onSuccess({ response: setSomethingHere })}` . unless the library is just supposed to return a response? if so then don't destructure in the function, just use a single argument and console log whatever you get from that

Comment: That's exactly what it was thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach you are trying to destructure the response data/object and pull field 'response' which does not exist i.e undefined

Change

```
const onSuccess = ({ response }) => {
```

to

```
const onSuccess = (response) => {
```

Comment: Followed your instructions and it worked perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: I need a little more reputation for the upvote but it has been marked as correct.